# Post-compilation custom action over source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, build-process

I need **before** a compilation process of my code `*.java`
Do some actions over them
To be applied on `target files` not `source files`

For example an action
comment ALL `System.out.println("");` statements

Need the output `target files` generated without print statements
BUT my `source code files` still with print statements

Note : development under `Eclipse` IDE

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you’re using the right tool for your task?

It’s much simpler to use a `static final boolean` variable controlling whether certain code fragments ought to be executed. You may arrange the value as a compile time constant; in this case the code disabled via this flag is even not present in the resulting byte code. But it may also be a runtime configuration, e.g.

> static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.getBoolean("myapp.debug");
>
> …
>
> if(DEBUG) System.out.println(something);

In this case the command line option `-Dmyapp.debug=true` may enable the printout.

There is no performance difference between these variants ( and to your pre-processing approach as well). The JIT is smart enough to eliminate all conditional code at runtime.